Unable to Connect to Azurite Container From Another Container in Docker Using TestContainers .NET Provided Connection String
I'm playing around with some integration tests using TestContainers for .NET, Azurite and an Azure Function App.
I have an Azurite TestContainer declared:
_azuriteContainer = new AzuriteBuilder()
    .Build();

Which provides (in my environment) a connection string by calling _azuriteContainer.GetConnectionString() of
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:59273/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:59274/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:59275/devstoreaccount1

Please note that this is generating a random external port number as expected as the underlying AzuriteBuilder is calling .WithPortBinding(BlobPort, true) etc.
The container spins up successfully and the connection string can be used to connect to the Azurite instance from my host machine (e.g. test project tests/Azure Storage Explorer) without issue.
I'm then composing and spinning up my Functions App container using TestContainers:
_functionsContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
    .WithImage(_functionsImage)
    .WithPortBinding(80, true)
    .WithWaitStrategy(
        Wait.ForUnixContainer()
            .UntilHttpRequestIsSucceeded(r => r.ForPort(80)))
    .WithEnvironment(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "AzureWebJobsStorage", _azuriteContainer.GetConnectionString() }
    })
    .Build();

The Functions App host within the container is initially starting successfully, however within the logs I can see that it's unable to communicate with the Azurite instance, with error message Connection refused (127.0.0.1:59274), which leads to the host process terminating. I've verified that the AzureWebJobsStorage environment variable is being set as expected and that the Azurite instance is still running.
My understanding of Docker is that the Functions App container should be able to communicate with the Azurite container on ports that are exposed externally to the host, which is the case in this instance as Azurite is available to the host via it's published connection string (confirmed by connecting to Azurite from Azure Storage Explorer) - what am I missing here? Why can't the Functions App running in the container access Azurite via its externally available ports as expected?
I've gone a bit further with my investigation by defining a network, adding both containers to that network, defining a network alias for the Azurite container and fudging the connection string:
_network = new NetworkBuilder()
    .Build();

_azuriteContainer = new AzuriteBuilder()
    .WithNetwork(_network)
    .WithNetworkAliases("azurite")
    .Build();

var internalAzuriteConnectionString = _azuriteContainer.GetConnectionString()
    .Replace($"{_azuriteContainer.Hostname}:{_azuriteContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(AzuriteBuilder.BlobPort)}" , $"azurite:{AzuriteBuilder.BlobPort}")
    .Replace($"{_azuriteContainer.Hostname}:{_azuriteContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(AzuriteBuilder.QueuePort)}", $"azurite:{AzuriteBuilder.QueuePort}")
    .Replace($"{_azuriteContainer.Hostname}:{_azuriteContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(AzuriteBuilder.TablePort)}", $"azurite:{AzuriteBuilder.TablePort}");

_functionsContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
    .WithImage(_functionsImage)
    .WithNetwork(_network)
    .WithPortBinding(80, true)
    .WithWaitStrategy(
        Wait.ForUnixContainer()
            .UntilHttpRequestIsSucceeded(r => r.ForPort(80)))
    .WithEnvironment(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "AzureWebJobsStorage", internalAzuriteConnectionString }
    })
    .Build();

This works perfectly, with the Functions App able to communicate with Azurite container to container, but the fudging of the connection string seems fragile and dirty, the approach seems unnecessary and I'd rather reduce the complexity/maintenance burden as much as possible.

To connect two container to communicate with each other they need to be on same network. create a docker network and run both container on the same network.  that is why when you creating network its working fine

Using networks is IMO the right approach here. Would this feel fine for you, if the Azurite module would provide network-aware connection strings?

@KevinWittek I don't necessarily have an aversion to the networks approach, other than the fudging of the connection strings - so yes if the Azurite container could do that it would be helpful. However, I do want to understand what I'm missing/potentially misinterpreting when it comes to accessing Azurite via it's publicly exposed endpoints - everything I've read on the subject says this should just work out of the box but it doesn't.

As I mentioned in comments to allow container to communicate with each other they need to be deployed or run on same network, A docker network need to be created for that.
Below code worked for me with connection string as Azurite ports are 10001(blob), 10001(queue), 10002(table). you need to map ports of host ports on these ports and use them.
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DotNet.Testcontainers.Builders;
using DotNet.Testcontainers.Containers;
using DotNet.Testcontainers.Networks;
using Testcontainers.Azurite;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a Docker network
        var _network = new NetworkBuilder()
            .Build();

        var _azuriteContainer = new AzuriteBuilder()
            .WithNetwork(_network)
            .WithNetworkAliases("azurite")
            .WithPortBinding(10000, 10000) // Blob
            .WithPortBinding(10001, 10001) // Queue
            .WithPortBinding(10002, 10002) // Table
            .Build();

        _azuriteContainer.StartAsync().Wait();
        
        var azuriteConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxKBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://azurite:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://azurite:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://azurite:10002/devstoreaccount1";

        // Configure and start the Functions App container with the same network and connection string
        var _functionsContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
            .WithImage("shandilyavivek/funcdotnet:0.0.1") // Replace with your Functions App image
            .WithNetwork(_network)
            .WithPortBinding(80, true)
            .WithWaitStrategy(
                Wait.ForUnixContainer()
                    .UntilHttpRequestIsSucceeded(r => r.ForPort(80)))
            .WithEnvironment(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "AzureWebJobsStorage", azuriteConnectionString }
            })
            
            .Build();

        _functionsContainer.StartAsync().Wait();
    }
}

OUTPUT:


I have used Timer Trigger as it requires to connect to azurite or azure storage to run.


This unfortunately doesn't address the question asked, it's merely a regurgitation of my findings that had already been stated.
You say that for the two containers to communicate, they "need to be on the same network" - do you have any documentation to back this up?
As I stated, it's my understanding that container to container communication should be possible over ports that are exposed externally to the host (as the container's DNS is the same as the host when using the bridge network adapter, which is default) - can you provide documentation that refutes this?

@James Law Check these documents 1. https://docs.docker.com/network/
2. https://docs.docker.com/guides/docker-concepts/running-containers/multi-container-applications/#run-the-containers

Which parts of those documents are you referring to? Can you provide a quote or a snippet that backs up your point please?

@james Law In the 2nd link the first point mentions when multi-container you need to deploy a network to communicate through. You are deploying a multi-container one container for azurite and another container for function app image

It also says "Containers have networking enabled by default, and they can make outgoing connections.", which means services made available to the host should also be available to other containers on their external points - which was my original question.

@JamesLaw Yes networking is enabled by default, its like plug and play you do not need to do any configuration with created network. You just need to create a network and use it during Docker run and network configuration is configured automatically.

The "they can make outgoing connections" was the significant part of that sentence. Thank you for your input, but I don't think you're able to get me closer to answering the question I actually asked.
